# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I'm having a problem with `np.append`.

I'm trying to duplicate the last column of 20x361 matrix `n_list_converted` by using the code below:

```
n_last = []
n_last = n_list_converted[:, -1]
n_lists = np.append(n_list_converted, n_last, axis=1)
```

But I get error:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

However, I've checked the matrix dimensions by doing

```
 print(n_last.shape, type(n_last), n_list_converted.shape, type(n_list_converted))
```

and I get

> (20L,)  (20L, 361L)

so the dimensions match? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Try `np.column_stack`.

Comment: It worked! But why?

Comment: try axis=None for appending empty arrays

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I start with a 3x4 array, and concatenate a 3x1 array, with axis 1, I get a 3x5 array:

```
In [911]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [912]: np.concatenate([x,x[:,-1:]], axis=1)
Out[912]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 11]])
In [913]: x.shape,x[:,-1:].shape
Out[913]: ((3, 4), (3, 1))
```

Note that both inputs to concatenate have 2 dimensions.

Omit the `:`, and `x[:,-1]` is (3,) shape - it is 1d, and hence the error:

```
In [914]: np.concatenate([x,x[:,-1]], axis=1)
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

The code for `np.append` is (in this case where axis is specified)

```
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

So with a slight change of syntax `append` works.  Instead of a list it takes 2 arguments.  It imitates the list `append` is syntax, but should not be confused with that list method.

```
In [916]: np.append(x, x[:,-1:], axis=1)
Out[916]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 11]])
```

`np.hstack` first makes sure all inputs are `atleast_1d`, and then does concatenate:

```
return np.concatenate([np.atleast_1d(a) for a in arrs], 1)
```

So it requires the same `x[:,-1:]` input.  Essentially the same action.

`np.column_stack` also does a concatenate on axis 1.  But first it passes 1d inputs through

```
array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
```

This is a general way of turning that (3,) array into a (3,1) array.

```
In [922]: np.array(x[:,-1], copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
Out[922]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 7],
       [11]])
In [923]: np.column_stack([x,x[:,-1]])
Out[923]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 11]])
```

All these 'stacks' can be convenient, but in the long run, it's important to understand dimensions and the base `np.concatenate`.  Also know how to look up the code for functions like this.  I use the `ipython` `??` magic a lot.

And in time tests, the `np.concatenate` is noticeably faster - with a small array like this the extra layers of function calls makes a big time difference.

Comment: This seems crazy to me. Why would numpy define arrays as [m,] and not [m,1] by default?

Comment: @Sean, in MATLAB where everything is 2d (or more) and Fortran/column major is the default, a column vector (m,1) shape may be most natural.  But `numpy` is Python, written in C. and is used for more than linear algebra.  `np.array([1,2,3])` is a lot simpler to type and display than `np.array([[1],[2],[3]])`.  A 1d array maps naturally to/from a simple Python list of numbers.  And with row-major ordering, the leading dimension is outer most, so a (m,) is a lot more like a (1,m) than a (m,1).  But it's trivial to change between these 3 shapes.

Answer (score 13):

(n,) and (n,1) are not the same shape. Try casting the vector to an array by using the `[:, None]` notation:

```
n_lists = np.append(n_list_converted, n_last[:, None], axis=1)
```

Alternatively, when extracting `n_last` you can use

```
n_last = n_list_converted[:, -1:]
```

to get a `(20, 1)` array.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why you get your error is because a "1 by n" matrix is different from an array of length n.

I recommend using `hstack()` and `vstack()` instead.
Like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(32).reshape(4,8) # 4 rows 8 columns matrix.
b = a[:,-1:]                    # last column of that matrix.

result = np.hstack((a,b))       # stack them horizontally like this:
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  7],
#       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15],
#       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23],
#       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 31]])
```

Notice the repeated "7, 15, 23, 31" column.
Also, notice that I used `a[:,-1:]` instead of `a[:,-1]`. My version generates a column:

```
array([[7],
       [15],
       [23],
       [31]])
```

Instead of a row `array([7,15,23,31])`

---

Edit: `append()` is *much* slower. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744459/4317303).

Comment: `np.append` is slower than list `.append`; but comparable to the `stacks`.  It uses `np.concatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj So... As I was saying using `append` vs `stack` is the same with 2 matrices and `stack` is better for more than 2 elements, so `stack` is always _at least as good as_ `append`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also cast (n,) to (n,1) by enclosing within brackets [ ].

e.g. Instead of `np.append(b,a,axis=0)` use `np.append(b,[a],axis=0)`

```
a=[1,2]
b=[[5,6],[7,8]]
np.append(b,[a],axis=0)
```

returns

```
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: And the opposite also works: `b=[1,2]; a=[[5,6],[7,8]]; np.append([b],a,axis=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `np.row_stack((ndarray_1, ndarray_2, ..., ndarray_nth))`

Assuming your ndarrays are indeed the same shape, this should work for you

```
n_last = []
n_last = n_list_converted[:, -1]
n_lists = np.row_stack((n_list_converted, n_last))
```