# problem appending columns and rows using numpy append and hstack

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10,25).reshape(5,5)
rowsums = np.array([sum(row) for row in X])
print(X.shape)       >>> (5,5)
print(rowsums.shape) >>> (5,)

all_data = np.append(X, rowsums, axis=1)
>>>> ValueError: all input arrays must have same number of dimensions...

all_data = np.hstack((X, rowsums))
>>>> ValueError: all input arrays must have same number of dimensions...

all_data = np.concatenate((X, rowsums), axis=1) 
>>>> ValueError: all input arrays must have same number of dimensions...
```

Ok, so I assume that the shape of my row sums has to be (5,1) and indeed rowsums.reshape(5,1) does the trick. **But why?** I guess I'm being dense here but doesn't shape (5, 1) look like this:

```
[[],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

Which kinda makes sense for a column... However when I want to append a row, without the append function flattening my ndarray, I have to reshape it (1,5) even though it is already in the exact same shape as every other row in the ndarray.

a row in a 2d ndarray looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

but numpy wants me to reshape it as

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

when no existing row looks like that. I shouldn't question, I suppose, but something seems weird to me.

Comment: It all comes down to using `concatenate` correctly - all arrays have to have the same number of dimensions, and all but one dimension has to match.  `append` is a superficial wrapper to `concatenate` (especially when specifying `axis`.

Comment: @hpaulj when you say same number of dimensions, you mean the number of elements in the shape tuple?

Comment: To make a (5,6) array, you need to join the (5,5) with a (5,1).  To make a (6,5) add a (1,5).   Yes, number of dimensions is the length of the shape tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848759/valueerror-all-the-input-arrays-must-have-same-number-of-dimensions)